# Is double saving a new entity instance with a Spring data 2 JpaRepository correct?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two entities in a bi-directional many to many relationship.

A <-> many to many <-> B

I have an endpoint where a client can create an instance of A, and at the same time add some number of B entities to that A, by passing in an array of B entity id keys. Please keep in mind **that these B entities already exist in the database**. There is no business or software design case for tightly coupling their creation to the creation of A.

So class A looks like this, and B is the same, but with references to A.

```
@Entity
class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;

    @ManyToMany
    List<B> bs;

    String someValue;

    int someValue2;

    // With some getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

So at first try my endpoint code looks like this.

```
public A createA(@RequestBody A aToCreate) {
    A savedA = aRepository.save(aToCreate);
    savedA.getbs().forEach(b -> Service.callWithBValue(b.getImportantValue());
}
```

And the client would submit a JSON request like this to create a new A which would contain links to B with id 3, and B with id 4.

```
 {
     "bs": [{id:3}, {id:10}],
     "someValue": "not important",
     "someValue2": 1
 }
```

Okay so everything's working fine, I see all the fields deserializing okay, and then I go to save my new A instance using.

```
aRepository.save(aToCreate);
```

And that works great... except for the fact that I need all the data associated with the b entity instances, but the A object returned by `aRepository.save()` has only populated the autofill fields on A, and done nothing with the B entities. They're still just hollow entities who only have their ids set.

Wut.

So I go looking around, and apparently SimpleJpaRepository does this.

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

And since the A entity is brand new, it only persists the A entity, but it doesn't merge it so I don't get any of the rich B data. So okay, if I modify my code to take this into account I get this.

```
public A createA(@RequestBody A aToCreate) {
    A savedA = aRepository.save(aRepository.save(aToCreate));
    savedA.getbs().forEach(b -> Service.callWithBValue(b.getImportantValue());
}
```

Which works just fine. The second pass through the repository service it merges instead of persists, so the B relationships get hydrated.

My question is: Is this correct, or is there something else I can do that doesn't look so ineloquent and awful?

To be clear this ONLY matters when creating a brand new instance of A, and once A is in the database, this isn't an issue anymore because the SimpleJpaRepository will flow into the `em.merge()` line of code. Also I have tried different CascadingType annotations on the relationship but none of them are what I want. Cascading is about persisting the state of the parent entity's view of its children, to its children, but what I want to do is hydrate the child entities on new instance creation, instead of having to make two trips to the database.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a new A, `aToCreate` and `savedA` are the same instance because that is what the JPA spec madates:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist(java.lang.Object)

> Make an instance managed and persistent.

Spring Data simply returns the same instance so persist/merge can be abstracted into one method.

If the B instances you wish to associate with A are existing entities then you need to fetch a reference to these existing instances and set them on A. You can do this without a database hit by using the `T getOne(ID id)` method of Spring Data's JpaRepository:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/api/

You can do this in your controller or possibly via a custom deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up going with. This gives the caller the ability to save and hydrate the instance in one call, and explains what the heck is going on. All my Repository instances now extend this base instance.

```
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

    /**
     * Saves an instance twice so that it's forced to persist AND then merge. This should only be used for new detached entities that need to be saved, and who also have related entities they want data about hydrated into their object.
     */
    @Transactional
    default T saveAndHydrate(T save) {
        return this.save(this.save(save));
    }
}
```